# Logout functionality on SSRS WebPortal

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2016

I am able to setup and run the SSRS 2016 environment for reporting purposes

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/web-portal-ssrs-native-mode

When i try to access the portal [ similar to the one explained in above link]  i can see all my reports and all is working .

ON top right corner of the web portal it shows the user details who currently accessed the portal and its by default the windows user who logged in to the windows. But in a specific scenario i have multiple windows users and i have to to access this report as a different windows user.

For this now i am  doing the steps

```
close the browser 
clear cache 
open browser and reload report url [localhost/report/browse]
it will ask to input user name and password  and i am able to logged in as different user
```

But is it possible to implement a logout kind of feature similar to webapps so we can redirects to Login page again in SSRS 2016 Web Portal . Is it possible ? Since i cant see anything in the documentation related to this. Can someone helps to get an idea about the implementation

Comment: Pre Ssrs2016 it was possible; I was able to load my own HttpModule and manipulate the responses to inject a "logout" link into the responses. Since then, they've switched to a newer request pipeline than the old Asp.Net one. I've been able to load a custom .dll into the "Portal" of Ssrs2019, but I wasn't able to hook into that pipeline. From other 'Net posts out there, it appears no one else has figured out how to manipulate the "Portal" either.

Answer (score 0):

I have this issue a lot while trying to setup sensible hierarchical SSRS security based on AD Groups and SSRS Server Roles and SSRS Folder Security Roles.  After my browser caches creds from my NTLM challenge response, I can open an Incognito browser and login with different creds.